# In routes, match to #index does not work...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm setting up my website such that

`www.website.com/articles/2013/07` will list all articles from 2013 in July and 
`www.website.com/articles/2013` will list all articles in 2013
`www.website.com/articles/2013/07/title-of-article` will list just the specific article

However, I am able to get only the first and last of the above 3 to work. Entering the url
`www.website.com/articles/2013` is not working properly. Specifically, I get a `noMethodError in Articles#show` which doesn't make sense to me because I have matched the route to `Articles#index`.

Can someone please explain what's going on here? I don't see where I am making a mistake.

Routes:

```
match "/articles/:year", :to => "articles#index",
:constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/ }, :as=> :posts_year

match "/articles/:year/:month", :to => "articles#index",
:constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/ }, :as => :posts_month

match "/articles/:year/:month/:slug", :to => "articles#show", 
:constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{1,2}/, :slug => /[a-z0-9\-]+/ }, :as => :posts_date
```

and in my model I have:

```
def year
  created_at.year
end

def month
  created_at.strftime("%m")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `resources :articles` in your routes file? If you do, that explains the error. Move `resources :articles` below the routes you mentioned in your question and everything should work fine. Alternatively you could change it to:

```
resources :articles, :except => :show
```

Comment: Literally just figured it out...silly me. Thanks I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that if you've defined articles as a resource, then the default show/:id route is taking precedence over your :posts_year route. Maybe try `resources :articles, :except => [:show]`